# vimrc stacking windows

Tags: vim

I would like to stack NERDTree and TagBar in Vim, like below. How does one accomplish this?

```
----------------------------
| NERDTree |               |
|          |               |
|          |               |
+----------|               |
| tagbar   |               |
|          |               |
|          |               |
+---------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is sort of brute force and I don't use either of those plugins but you should be able to do...

1. Put the cursor in tagbar, type `<C-W>K` to make it full-width on top.
2. Put the cursor in NERDTree, type `<C-W>K` to make it full-width on top, now above tagbar.
3. Put the cursor in the empty window and type `<C-W>L` to make it full-height, to the right of the stacked windows.